# BigQuery - invoke query upon insert to a table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Here is my use case.

A new CSV file is uploaded into GCS bucket, next the data is inserted into BigQuery table, after the data is in BigQuery a post processing query should be triggered upon the insert event.

To implement the first step I created a cloud function in Python that loads the data from GCS bucket to BigQuery table.

I am struggling with the second step, since BigQuery doesn't support the notion of db triggers.

Right now I am using scheduled queries which is not ideal, since it runs even if the underlying table doesn't change.

I am not willing to use composer due to the cost involved, I am looking for a simple cost-effective solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple ways to achieve this. Two simple ones can be:

1. You can use the same cloud function which loads data from GCS->BQ to run an additional query upon load completion.
2. From your cloud function you can set a unique identifier in some type of queue (Pub/Sub, Redis, RabbitMQ, etc.) which is being polled by one of your processes at discrete intervals and upon seeing any new entry, it can can run the post-processing query. This way, the second process doesn't trigger a BQ query blindly, and always runs when it sees a new entry in the queue. You can read on how to publish a Pub/Sub message [here](http://%5B1%5D:%20https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#python). Your other process can be either a cron job or simply another cloud function which you can trigger on-demand whenever you want.
3. Another option (a more primitive one) could be sending a tiny JSON file to some GCS bucket folder containing something like `{"status": True}` upon completion of loading data into BQ. And then tie another cloud function to trigger the post-processing BQ query as soon as a new file is dropped into that GCS bucket folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, can you elaborate on the second way using Pub/Sub.

Comment: I added some details.

Comment: Eventually I followed your first proposal to append the code to the existing cloud function, and it turns out to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional option to consider:

Your cloud function, upon loading data, can send some message (maybe with some relevant details if required) into a PubSub topic (it will take a few milliseconds) - you modify your cloud function is such way, and create a PubSub topic for this purpose.

On the other side of this topic, there is another cloud function, which is triggered automatically. You can develop that cloud function and implement any functionality you need.